# React-Native-Camera can't compile to android emulator

Tags: camera, react-native

I am busy trying to implement camera functionality into an app I am writing in react-native. I have installed react-native-camera via npm and have this working solidly in IOS.

When I try and run on android, the project does not build and throws below error

> node_modules/react-native-camera/android/src/main/java/org/reactnative/camera/events/BarCodeReadEvent.java:27: error: no suitable method found for init(int)

I have specified the correct android sdk build tools as described on https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera.

I can run simple projects on my android emulator but as soon as I link the react-native-camera, I am unable to build. Does anyone have any ideas, or experience with this?

I am developing on a mac and as mentioned above. Everything works perfectly on the IOS app.

Comment: Have you tried linking the project manually?

Comment: I have. And I have doubled checked it line for line.

Comment: @sfratini I have also made sure my gradle file has the android build tools that they mention.

Comment: Is this error at building time or when you run the emulator? Because I don't think you can use the camera on an emulator

Comment: @sfratini at build time. It gets to 32% build complete and then fails with above error message. I have also posted an issue on the github page to see if they perhaps know why this is happening